# Is there a way to turn off a Tampermonkey script on every website except for those I choose?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I have a Tampermonkey script that is enabled on all websites. How can I make this script only run on one or some websites? I went into the script settings and found the Includes/Excludes text fields there, what should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a script to only run on some sites, you should change the script's `@include` or `@match` blocks accordingly. [For example](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules), taken from GM's wiki:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include     http://www.example.com/foo/*
// @include     http://www.example.org/*.bar
// @exclude     http://www.example.com/foo/baz
// ==/UserScript==
```

will run on `example.com/foo/`, and on `example.com` when `bar` is included in the rest of the URL - *except* when the path is `foo/baz`.

You can use either globs or regular expressions in `@include`. For regular expressions, surround the expression with a single slash, eg:

```
// @include    /^example\.com$/
```

Comment: I see. I thought the scripts were enabled on all sites by default, but they are so due to Original matches `*://*/*` block, which enables them on all sites. I disabled Original matches and added my sites to User matches. Thanks!